# Community wiki -- Does it retroactively reassign votes?

Tags: support, community-wiki, voting, reputation-recalc

When I have a question or answer that is getting a few downvotes and I come to realize it is a bad post, but that it should not be deleted, I will commonly edit the post to be community wiki so I stop losing rep on it.

My question is, if a question had +5 votes before being marked community wiki, after marking it CW do these votes get reassigned to the Community user(and thus, you would lose 5 votes during a recalc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All votes before the CW switch still count.

Answer (score 0):

Nope